# Saving password in webview

Tags: webview, passwords, save

Why is that the web browsers in Android can save login credentials even now for a website but a webview can't do the same (saving password depricated after API 18+).
I don't see much difference between a browser and a webview. How is it possible in a browser? Is there a possibility to save credentials in webview?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your webview:

```
mWebView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/cache");
mWebView.getSettings().setDatabasePath(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/databases");
```